# How to get last character of string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

In python you can say `print "String"[-1]` and it would print be the last character, 'g'. Is there an equivalent for this in c++?

Comment: Is your question about C++ strings or C strings? Maybe your confusion is because all the answers below use C++ strings, but maybe your question is about C strings.

Comment: No I use C++                      .                        .

Comment: @HamzaTahboub: not sure if you understood john's point: in C++ there is a `std::string` library type which you can use like this: `std::string s("String"); std::cout << s.back() << '\n';`.  And, there are C style NUL-terminated ASCIIZ strings.  String literals like `"String"` are character arrays in ASCIIZ format and easily decay to `const char*`s to their first character.  You can not call `"String".back();`, but can write a function `char back(const char* p) { return p[strlen(p) - 1]; }`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use [string.back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/back/) to get a reference to the last character in the string. The last character of the string is the first character in the reversed string, so [string.rbegin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/) will give you an iterator to the last character.

Comment: do i need any kind of library to use these because its not working with me

Comment: yes i do but it says .back() doesn't exist, maybe i have a old or new version of c++

Comment: @john back() and front() was added to std::string in the c++11 standard.

Comment: I'll just try another IDE

Comment: @john `error: request for member 'rbegin' in '"123"', which is of non-class type 'const char [4]'` I get this with all IDEs and with rbegin and back

Comment: @HamzaTahboub You asked about strings. Why are you testing on an array of characters?

Comment: @HamzaTahboub The problem is what I thought, you are trying to apply C++ string functions to a C string. Have a look at Tim's answer or look at Tony D's comment above.

Answer (score 19):

Use the `back()` function for `std::string`:

```
std::string str ("Some string");
cout << str.back()
```

**Output:**

```
g
```

Answer (score 7):

For C strings, it is

```
String[strlen(String) - 1];
```

For C++ style strings, it is either

```
String.back();
*String.rbegin();
String[String.length() - 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function:

```
my_string.back();
```

If you want to output it, then:

```
#include <iostream>
std::cout << my_string.back();
```